# Can't find "Foundation" option while creating Objective-C Project in XCode 6

Tags: xcode

I am new to Objective-C and following Big Nerd Ranch guide. In chapter 13, it asks to make a foundation project. I am using Xcode 6 with Mac OS X Yosemite, but can't find any Foundation option while creating project.
There are four language options which i can see i.e., C, C++, Objective-C and Swift. Which one should i choose?? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation is just one of Apple's frameworks. I assume it's the BNR book about Objective-c (great book btw), in which case I think the type you're looking for is a Command Line Tool project. It uses the Foundation framework by default. [image: Command Line Tool]

I found an old image of Xcode where there used to be a drop down menu to select type, but it seems to have been removed from the newer version of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear! Could you mark my answer as correct in that case? :)